# Is it correct to say frozen ice?

Tags: phrases

Is it correct to say this, when it is frozen water. Not frozen ice, because it sounds weird.  but is there such thing as frozen ice.  It's frozen water.

Comment: As correct as liquid water would be... It doesn't make sense, but it's grammatically sound.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a grammar problem.  Frozen ice, boiled steam, etc., all work within the syntax of the language.  This is really a philosophical question.

Consider that in some places, like Philadelphia, they serve "water ice" (although it sounds like "wudder ice").

Answer (score 0):

By definition, ice is frozen water, just as steam is vaporized water. Describing ice as frozen or steam as vaporized is unnecessary.